# Can someone track my location if I clicked on a link to Google Maps?

Tags: privacy, geolocation

I was using a dating app, and this person sent a link. When I clicked on it, it led me to Google Maps and I exited immediately, without seeing which location it was showing.

I'm scared the person now knows my home address/ip address or some other personal info. I don't know whether the guy was sharing his location, or whether it was some trick. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry to much about this.

It is possible the person who sent the link now knows your IP address. However, that doesn't give them very much information. It can be used to figure out roughly what city you probably are in, but it won't get any more precise than that.

Unless they discovered some major vulnerability in your browser, your device or in Google Maps, they can't figure out where you are just because you click a link. This is not very likely and not something I would worry about in a situation like this.

If you gave the website some extra permissions, if you downloaded something, entered some information or did something else on the site than just merely visiting it, there would be bigger risks involved.

Comment: While I agree with your answer, the unknown is the **Dating App** . One would hope that the dating app doesn't violate privacy and automatically send unapproved personal information.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not download anything which I assume you did not, they can obtain your IP address, browser, device type(IPhoneX etc.), language, your ISP(Internet service provider) etc. And, if you are using the app from a campus, they can see which university you are from because most universities use their own ISPs